# updating sql server database using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

im having issues updating my database from a webform. I use a series of textboxes and dropdownlists which are populated by the datasource but for some reason i cant update them.

Basically the primary key of a row is passed into the next page where the textboxes,drop down lists are populated with the data from that row.

Here is what i have tried so far

```
    //Update the record with new information entered into controls
    protected void UpdateBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=stephenp\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Asset management System DB;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE Peripherals SET PeripheralType=@PeripheralType, Model=@Model, PeripheralSerialNumber=@SerialNum, " +
                "Company = @Company, Department=@Department, Status=@Status, WarrantyExpirationDate=@Warranty, PeripheralCapexNumber=@CapexNum, " +
                "IPAddress=@IPAddress, LastModifiedDate = @LastMD, LastModifiedBy=@LastMB WHERE (PeripheralTagNumber = @PeripheralTagNumber)";


          //try
           //{
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeripheralType", TypeDDL.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", ModelTB.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", SerialNumTB.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", CompanyDDL.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", DepartmentDDL.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", StatusDDL.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Warranty", DateTime.Parse(WarrantyTB.Text.Trim()).ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CapexNum", CapexNumTB.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAddress", IPAddressTB.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastMD", DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastMB", Session["username"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PeripheralTagNumber", ID);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
             }
           //}
            //catch (SqlException ex) { }
        }

        this.getData();
    }
```

thanks

Comment: are you getting errors?

Comment: What is your ploblem?

Comment: Well, what is your issue with that code? Exceptions? Error messages? Don't update anything? Please be more specific

Comment: Also some of your columns seems to be of type dateTime or smalldatetime (LastModifiedDate etc) but you pass a string as a parameter value.

Comment: Hi, i dont get any exceptions whatsoever, it just focuses and then does nothing. It does not update the database on the server side either

Comment: How do you check that the update has failed? Do you open the Database using the Server Explorer window inside Visual Studio?

Comment: I open the database using sql server management studio and run a query to select the row im looking for. Its an odd one because it should be updating but it does nothing... not even an error message to give you some idea. My theory is that it could be the sql statement but ive looked at it 100 times and cant seem to see an issue

Comment: I'd advise one of three things.Either debug your web form, put a breakpoint when you start add the last parameter and check the value of ID that is being passed to the command, if you are getting no errors, but no update it is likely `ID` is not what you think it is. Alternatively, run SQL Server Profiler and catch the exact SQL that is being passed to the database, this will also tell you what the value of the parameters being passed is. Finally, check what `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns, if this is -1 you know your transaction has been rolled back.

Comment: Problem is solved! I regrettably forgot to use if(!IsPostBack) in my main method meaning that when i made the call to update the database it was still updating, yet the values were being updated with the current values in the database i.e. the values were being updated with the exact same values. Adding if(!IsPostBack) solved the issue by allowing the call to update with new values entered into the textboxes/dropdownlists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AddWithValue could lead to some subtle bugs. For example if your column LastModifiedDate is of datetime type you should pass a DateTime value as the second parameter in AddWithValue, not a string.
The same for the WarrantyDate

You could try to change these lines

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastMD", DateTime.Now.Date);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Warranty", DateTime.Parse(WarrantyTB.Text.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be use block try / catch when you construct your SqlCommand and when you execute your query.

If there is no update in database, you may have a problem with your command.

Comment: Problem is solved! I regrettably forgot to use if(!IsPostBack) in my main method meaning that when i made the call to update the database it was still updating, yet the values were being updated with the current values in the database i.e. the values were being updated with the exact same values. Adding if(!IsPostBack) solved the issue by allowing the call to update with new values entered into the textboxes/dropdownlists.